# Type-check by array size?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm working on building a library for (effectively) permutations; the goal is to allow you to specify and compose permutations on n elements. So, for example, I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
let p1 = Permutation([4,3,2,1])
let p2 = Permutation([1,3,2,4])
p1 * p2 // -> Permutation([4,2,3,1])
```

In general, it only makes sense to compose permutations of the same size. So for example:

```
let p3 = Permutation([1,2,3])
p1 * p3 // Error
```

Obviously I can check the sizes when I do the composition and either throw an exception or return `nil`; but both of these options involve more boilerplate (either marking every composition with `try` or unpacking every result). Because it never makes sense to compose permutations of different lengths, I'd prefer to have a compile-time error — in essence, I want permutations of different lengths to be of different types.

I'm ok with having to specify a finite number of types — my ultimate use case probably only cares about a finite range of sizes. However, there will eventually be other types that I might want to compose with permutations (e.g. permutation sequences or semantically-typed subsets of permutations) for which the same restriction will apply — so I'd prefer the type-checking be done in some generic way.

(If it helps, essentially what I'm looking for is a way to approximate Julia's `NTuple` types, which are parameterized by the number of elements.)

### What I've tried

My best attempt so far involves dummy length "types" (i.e. a separate uninstantiable type for each length):

```
protocol LengthProtocol { }
enum Three: LengthProtocol { }
enum Four: LengthProtocol { }

struct Permutation<Length: LengthProtocol> {
  // ...

  static func *<S: LengthProtocol>(lhs: Permutation<S>, rhs: Permutation<S>) -> Permutation<S> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, type inference seems to fail, here:

```
let p1 = Permutation<Three>([1,2,3])
let p2 = Permutation<Three>([1,3,2])
p1 * p2 // ERROR: Cannot infer generic paramter S
```

Comment: "Const generics" is a search term that might help you find stuff relevant to this. They were added to Rust somewhat recently, but are generally a pretty rare feature. It'd be great to eventually have them in Swift, IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator should not be generic. It should use the existing `Length` type parameter, as declared in the struct.

```
static func *(lhs: Permutation<Length>, rhs: Permutation<Length>) -> Permutation<Length> {
    ...
}
```

The generic parameter `S` is only required, if you declare the operator *outside* of `Permutation`.

Also, I'd not allow public code to initialise `Permutation` with an array. Instead, expose initialisers with specific numbers of parameters, and constrain `Length` on each initialiser.

```
private init(_ array: [Int]) {
    // ...
}

init(_ a: Int, _ b: Int, _ c: Int, _ d: Int) where Length == Four {
    self.init([a, b, c, d])
}

init(_ a: Int, _ b: Int, _ c: Int) where Length == Three {
    self.init([a, b, c])
}
```